HP Elite Dragonfly G3 webcam (still) not recognized
I post again on this topic, since installing Ubuntu 24.04 didn't change anything. Still stuck with this cam for more than 1 year!
Any idea ?
5MP MIPI-RAW Infrared
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:0103 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.2
    bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 46.0 driver: dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1281x854~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,swrast platforms:
    active: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device inactive: gbm
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
    glx-v: 1.4 direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2)



How do I know? it doesn't seem to appear anywhere... (works fine on windows)
